# Jhipster React how to hide element based on user role

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I am using JHipster 5.0.1 and React. I have three buttons View, Edit, Delete. I want the Delete button only available if the user is Admin.

Here is my source code. Thanks for the help.

```
<td className="text-right">
   <div className="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${kategori.id}`} color="info" size="sm">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" />{' '}
          <span className="d-none d-md-inline">
              <Translate contentKey="entity.action.view">View</Translate>
          </span>
      </Button>
      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${kategori.id}/edit`} color="primary" size="sm">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" />{' '}
          <span className="d-none d-md-inline">
              <Translate contentKey="entity.action.edit">Edit</Translate>
          </span>
      </Button>
      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${kategori.id}/delete`} color="danger" size="sm">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" />{' '}
          <span className="d-none d-md-inline">
              <Translate contentKey="entity.action.delete">Delete</Translate>
          </span>
      </Button>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: There are many examples in generated code, look in app.tsx, isAdmin prop uses hasAnyAuthority()  and it's used in header.tsx

Comment: yes, it is const mapStateToProps in app.tsx. How do i inject the authetication into mapStateToProps entities files? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer function that handles connection is also setting a `isAdmin` property in store. There's an example of usage of this prop in the generated files.

Take a look at `src/main/webapp/app/app.tsx` to see how to get the prop from the store and in `src/main/webapp/app/shared/layout/header/header.tsx` to see how to use that prop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the variable containing the boolean for isadmin but for conditional rendering, you can do this :

```
{ isadmin && 
  <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${kategori.id}/delete`} color="danger"   size="sm">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" />{' '}
          <span className="d-none d-md-inline">
              <Translate contentKey="entity.action.delete">Delete</Translate>
          </span>
  </Button>
}
```